# Facebook API returns the post ID but the post is not showing up on Facebook

Tags: facebook, api, post

I am posting via API. The app returns the post id but when I do https://www.facebook.com/post-id-here facebook returns a page not found page. "Sorry, this page isn't available"

Why is that?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the URL you're looking for is https://graph.facebook.com/pos-id-here ? Let me know if that fixes it, or if you have any questions :)